# Does the US interview waiver program apply to people with a prior refusal of a non-US visa?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, us-visa

According to the US interviewer waiver qualifications, it states that:

> the applicant must not have been refused a visa since the issuance of the previous visa, or had a visa revoked, or have ever required a waiver,

Does this qualification apply to being refused visas from other countries, such as the UK, or is it limited to US visas only?

Comment: Can you edit your answer with what country are you applying in? The rules for the interview waivers are sepecific to the country

Answer (score 2):

It is limited to US visa refusals.

From FAQs *Do I qualify for interview waiver* https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/frequently-asked-questions/:

You may use the expanded interview waiver program if …

You have previously been issued ANY class of U.S. visa, AND

You have not been previously refused a U.S. visa, OR if you have previously been refused the refusal was subsequently overcome or waived (a 214b refusal is overcome whenever a visa is subsequently issued to the applicant.)